# Umbraco 7 protect images

Tags: image, umbraco7

If building an intranet, we would want users to be able to upload images for their own documents (eg, news items, blog entries and so on).
However, access to media seems to allow users to also replace images on existing media.

Therefore, they could presumably replace furniture (eg, site logo etc) as these would all be in the media folder.

I understand that users can be given a starting folder for the media tree (similar to that for editing documents), however, this would mean editing every single user to set their starting point, as there doesn't seem to be any way of doing this en masse eg by roles or user grouping.

Is there another solution, eg saving furniture in another way so that only admins can edit them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to assign actual rights to media items or folders.

But actually, if you have a sure fire way of knowing which starting node to assign to which users, it's not that tricky to do it programmatically:

```
var userService = UmbracoContext.Current.Application.Services.UserService;
var mediaService = UmbracoContext.Current.Application.Services.MediaService;
int total;

foreach (var user in userService.GetAll(0, 1000, out total))
{
    int targetMediaId = 0;

    switch(user.UserType.Id)
    {
        case 123:
            targetMediaId = 3;
            break;
        case 234:
            targetMediaId = 5;
            break;
    }
    user.StartMediaId = targetMediaId;

    userService.Save(user);
}
```

I've used UserType as an example of how you might know what to assign to who, as I don't know how you'll tell in the end. In principal you could "easily" go as far as, I dunno, create a media folder per user and assign it as their starting media node.

Comment: It can go anywhere, basically. You can put it in an ApplicationEventHandler class for it to run on startup - just remember to remove it again so ot doesn't run on EVERY startup after thst one time. Or put in a partial view macro, insert it on a page and visit the page ONCE. The example is for a one time execution, but you could hook something similar into a UserService.SavingUser (I think that's the name) event as well, so every new user has a starting node set on creation.

Comment: Thanks, Jannik, but as I am new to this, don't know where the code sits. You previously pointed me at App_Code for front end coding, but what about back office stuff - where does that physically sit ie the .cs file?

Comment: You could go to our.umbraco.org and look around? There's a lot of documentation there, including a section on events (okay, here's the link: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/ ).

Comment: Still doesn't tell you where to put the physical code files in the Umbraco file structure ! I'll keep searching... ;-) Thanks for your help

Comment: Alright alright :-) It's still App_Code - always App_Code if you don't want to compile the code. Can't remember what the other thing was we put in there, but if you already have an ApplicationEventHandler class, make an ApplicationStarted method and put it in there). That method has to have an override signature, which you can find in any of the Event examples ;-)

Comment: LOL, you're welcome, I just hope you're learning while doing :-)